# Python “for” problem - Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I wanna take array C2, size N,1, and make a array B, size N-1,1.

B[0] = C2[1]

B[1] = C2[2]

and so on. My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fields = "B:D"
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\file.xlsx', "Sheet2", usecols=fields)
N = 2

# Covariance calculation

C1 = data.cov() C2 = data.var()

B = np.zeros(shape=(N,1))

for i in B:
    B[i,1] = C2[i+1,1]
```

But the error is:

```
ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex
```

I know it is a simple mistake, but cant find where :S (new python user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, are you sure you need to be using numpy arrays? This seems like a job for python lists.

Next, what do you mean to be doing with `for i in B:`? what type is i?

In this case, iterating over B is going to set `i` to `[0.]`, and you can now see that the next line is going to fail in the substitution

```
    B[[0.],i] = C2[[0.]+1,1]
```

In addition, the call to `pd.var()` returns a 1-d series, so the second index isn't doing anything.

I think you want to iterate over N like

```
for i in range(N):
    B[i,1] = C2[i+1]
```

Comment: This way it tells me TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: My mistake answering before coffee. Fixed above.

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
Is it because of my variable types?
Cs is Series (3,). B is float64 (3,1)

Comment: I see. The variance member function in pandas returns a series (which is like a 1-d array or vector), so there's only one index to specify the location within the Series. So your `C2[i+1,1]` should be `C2[i+1]`. You don't need the second index.

Comment: Works! Thank you! for i in range(N):
    B[i] = C2[i+1]